# Using HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers to affect controls in the ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, triggers, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a `TreeView` with a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` (shown below) bound to a data relation in a dataset. The parent nodes represent parent parts and the children represent parts that make up the parent. In some cases the user will check the checkbox at the parent level to indicate they are replacing the entire part with all its children. At this point a textbox will appear for them to enter the new part number for the parent. So far I have that working.

What I need help with is, hiding the children when the parent checkbox is checked. I've been approaching this from the trigger path, but I can't seem to make a reference to any of the controls in the ItemTemplate from a trigger in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers`. Perhaps it's not possible?

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding MyParts}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
        <CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding ReplaceParent}"></CheckBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="NewParentPartNumberTextBox" Text="{Binding NewPartNumber}" Visibility="Collapsed"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChildPartNumber}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding NewChildPartNumber}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger SourceName="MyCheckBox" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="NewParentPartNumberTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </Trigger>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a XAML-only approach, but it might suit your needs:

Say your ViewModel/class-that-is-bound-to-your-parent-item looks like this:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public bool ReplaceParent {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> MyParts {get; set;}
}
```

You *could* try something like:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    private bool _replaceParent;
    private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> _originalParts = ....;
    public bool ReplaceParent 
    {
        get { return _replaceParent; }
        set
        {
            MyParts = value ? 
                      new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>() :
                      _originalParts;
            // omit: any property changed logic    
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> MyParts  {get; set;}
}
```

Basically, swap out the children collection with an empty list while you have the checkbox checked.